# Apache Zookeeper Common/Default Nodes Accessible Without ACL found

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

A security scan is reporting a vulnerability: "Apache Zookeeper Common/Default Nodes Accessible Without ACL found"

I have try to enable ACL in SOLR-8.4.1 and Zookeeper-3.5.5 to remediate VIT's But the scan still reports the vulnerability.

I have done the below changes.

solr.in.cmd

```
REM Settings for ZK ACL
set SOLR_ZK_CREDS_AND_ACLS=-DzkACLProvider=org.apache.solr.common.cloud.VMParamsAllAndReadonlyDigestZkACLProvider ^
-DzkCredentialsProvider=org.apache.solr.common.cloud.VMParamsSingleSetCredentialsDigestZkCredentialsProvider ^

-DzkDigestUsername=admin-user -DzkDigestPassword=******* ^

-DzkDigestReadonlyUsername=Admin -DzkDigestReadonlyPassword=********

 set SOLR_OPTS=%SOLR_OPTS% %SOLR_ZK_CREDS_AND_ACLS%
```

solr.xml

```
<str name="zkCredentialsProvider">${zkCredentialsProvider:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.VMParamsSingleSetCredentialsDigestZkCredentialsProvider}</str>
<str name="zkACLProvider">${zkACLProvider:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.VMParamsAllAndReadonlyDigestZkACLProvider}</str>
```

zkcli.bat

```
REM Settings for ZK ACL
set SOLR_ZK_CREDS_AND_ACLS=-DzkACLProvider=org.apache.solr.common.cloud.VMParamsAllAndReadonlyDigestZkACLProvider ^

 -DzkCredentialsProvider=org.apache.solr.common.cloud.VMParamsSingleSetCredentialsDigestZkCredentialsProvider ^

 -DzkDigestUsername=admin-user -DzkDigestPassword=****** ^

 -DzkDigestReadonlyUsername=Admin -DzkDigestReadonlyPassword=*******
```

What am I missing to fully enable ACL?

Comment: Some additional information about what it should be doing versus what it's actually doing would be helpful.

Comment: Please follow the below URL for more information and help to enable ACL. 
 https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/zookeeper-access-control.html

Comment: That is also good info, but doesn't answer my question. You've told us the steps you've taken to modify your system - good! Now, to test it out, what are you doing, what should happen, what is happening? (Example: "I'm logging in with a test user a created that should only be able to read data, but I am able to edit and delete things as well")

Comment: The problem statement, we have Vulnerability "Apache Zookeeper Common/Default Nodes Accessible Without ACL found" and this Vulnerability is thrown by the tool called as "Qualys scan". Basically this tool (Qualys scan) will scan the application and it will generate the report .

Comment: So, would it be accurate to say that after you've made the changes in the Question, the scan still reports the same vulnerability?

Comment: Yes, Those changes I have made which is shown above in my application still I am getting the vulnerability.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Nitish, Any solution to this question you found. We also have to enable ACL in zookeeper,we dont have any files in zookeeper directory except zkcli.cmd under zookeeper/bin. Windows is the OS. any idea how to enable ACL in this case ?